# How to use JavaScript reduce() method to add ranges between an interval

Tags: javascript

The program below is used to add the four ranges with the ranges array and display the result 139.

(20 - 1) + (11930 - 11904) + (12020 - 11931) + (6 - 1) = 139

However, I cannot quite understand the use of the start parameter and the zero (0) in the code.

Help me understand how they are processed in the program.

Thanks

```js
let ranges = [[1,20],[11904, 11930],[11931, 12020],[1,6]];
     console.log(ranges.reduce((start, [from, to]) =>{
       return start + (to - from);
     }, 0));
```

Comment: Reading the docs on [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) would probably clarify what those are for. The `0` is an initial value, and the `start` parameter is your accumulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Basics of `reduce`

Let's start simpler.  [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is a way of folding multiple values into a single one.  It accepts two arguments:

- a function of two values
- a starting point

This function should accept a value of your target type and the next element of your array, and it should return an element of your target type.<sup>1</sup>

So, what if we wanted to calculate the following?

```js
[19, 26, 89, 5] .reduce (
  (a, b) => a + b,
  0
)
```

Our function is simply addition, adding its two parameters together.  And our initial value is `0`.

Here's how it is processed:

```
[19, 26, 89, 5] .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)
                         `-------+-----'  |
                     +-----------|---------+
                     |           | 
                     |        +--+
                     |        |
                     V    ,-------,        
[19, 26, 89, 5]  |   0 |  (0   + 19) ==>  19
 ==                              ==

[19, 26, 89, 5]  |  19 |  (19  + 26) ==>  45
     ==                          ==

[19, 26, 89, 5]  |  45 |  (45  + 89) ==> 134
         ==                      ==

[19, 26, 89, 5]  | 134 |  (134 +  5) ==> 139
             =                    =       ^
                                           `----- final result
```

`reduce` is extremely powerful.  Functions such as `map`, `filter`, `find` and others can easily be built atop `reduce`, if we so chose.

### The callback function

Note that the target type and the array element type do not have to be the same.  Your function just has to accept an argument of the target type and one of the element type and combine them into a new target type.

So perhaps we would like to fold an array of Strings into a number representing the total number of characters in all of them.  We could write this as

```js
['Four', 'score', 'and', 'seven', 'years', 'ago']
  .reduce ((total, word) => total + word.length, 0) 
//=> 25
```

Our callback accepts a number and a word and returns a new number by adding the length of the word to the input number.

Or you could fold these into an object:

```js
['Four', 'score', 'and', 'seven', 'years', 'ago']
  .reduce ((all, word) => ({...all, [word]: word.length}), {})
//=> {Four: 4, score: 5, and: 3, seven: 5, years: 5, ago:3}
```

### Handling your ranges

For your sample case, the array elements are ranges represented as two element arrays, `[from, to]`.

We could write it like this:

```js
ranges.reduce((start, range) =>{
  return start + (range.to - range.from);
}, 0)
```

but JS's parameter destructuring gives us a slightly nicer syntax

```js
ranges.reduce((start, [from, to]) =>{
  return start + (to - from);
}, 0)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is an oversimplification.  The callback function can actually take two additional parameters, but they aren't relevant here, and I would suggest avoiding them as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Let `f` be the function defined for the first argument of the `reduce`.

`f` gets called for each element of `ranges`, where each element is of the form `[from, to]`, and returns `start + (to - from)`, where `start` is the value returned from the previous call to `f`.

For the *first* call to `f`, there is no previous value, so it has to be supplied in the call to `reduce`: hence, the second argument of `reduce` being 0.